# What's new for developers in Mobile Safari iOS 4.2

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios4, css

Does anyone know what the changes are to Safari in the iPad OS update coming in November, from a web application development standpoint?

Is there any expanded support for hardware acceleration, any changes to JavaScript, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers found: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios-accelerometer-websockets-html5

Comment: Another finding:  In Safari iOS 4.2, if you apply a CSS3 translate transform to a div, it will not render any content past 122900 pixels. This limitation did not exist in iOS 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

well i can tell you one thing beta 3 hosed my preventDefault() functionality